# assigning a variable inside the getJSON function

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, marionette

In Backbone & marionette, I'm using json to grab my translations. I'm doing this in my ItemView under the onBeforeRender function. But whenever I call the "this.model.set" function, I always get errors saying "TypeError: this.model is undefined". Is there a way to set a variable that's outside the getJSON to be assigned inside the getJSON function?

```
  onBeforeRender: function(model){

        //let's get the json translation file before we render the view 
        var jqXHR = $.getJSON("en.json", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            this.model.set({trans:jqXHR.responseJSON}); //it fails here

            return jqXHR.responseJSON;


        }).fail(function(data){

        }).then(function(data){

        }).done(function(data){
            console.debug(data)
        });

    },
```

Or if anyone has suggestions on how to do this better, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `this` in your `.getJSON` callback is not what you think. Use the following code:

```
var self = this;
var jqXHR = $.getJSON("en.json", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    self.model.set({trans:jqXHR.responseJSON}); //it fails here
    return jqXHR.responseJSON;
}).fail(function(data){

}).then(function(data){

}).done(function(data){
    console.debug(data)
});
```

In your code `this` points to the callback and not to the view.

Answer (score 1):

`this` probably isn't referring to what you think it is. Set some context and try again:

```
var that = this;
//let's get the json translation file before we render the view 
 var jqXHR = $.getJSON("en.json", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    that.model.set({trans:jqXHR.responseJSON}); //it fails here

    return jqXHR.responseJSON;
```